# Не листает таблицу c поиском, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: php, mysqli

Вот скрипт , помогите пожалуйста не хочет листать с таким поиском, если вывести просто таблицу всё прекрасно листает , а когда указан поиск по имени не хочет ..

```
  <?php
        // Параметры подключения к базе данных
        define('DB_SE','server67.0hosting.me');
        define('DB_LO','u8462856_test');
        define('DB_PA','koloiko555');
        define('DB_BA','u8462856_test');


        class DB {
            public static function connect() {
                static $db = null;
                if ($db==null) $db = new DB();
                return $db;
            }
            private $_handle = null;
            private function __construct() {
                $this->_handle = new mysqli(DB_SE, DB_LO, DB_PA, DB_BA);
                if ($this->_handle->connect_error) {
                    die('Connect Error (' . $this->_handle->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->_handle->connect_error);
                }
                $this->_handle->query("SET NAMES utf8");
            }
            public function __destruct() {
              $this->_handle->close();
            }
            public function Test() {
                return $this->_handle;
            }
            public function Query($query) {
                $query = $this->_handle->query($query);
                return $query;
            }
            public function QueryNumRows($query) {
                return (($query===false) ? 0 : mysqli_num_rows($query));
            }
            public function QueryArray($query) {
                if ($query===false) return false;

                unset($arr);
                $i = 0;
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        foreach ($row as $key => $value) $arr[$i][$key] = $value;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $arr = false;
                }
                unset($row);
                return $arr;
            }
            function ResultQueryArray($query) {
                return $this->QueryArray($this->Query($query));
            }
            function ResultQueryNumRows($query) {
                return $this->QueryNumRows($this->Query($query));
            }
        }

        function Query($query) {
          return DB::connect()->Query($query);
        }

        function QueryNumRows($query) {
          return DB::connect()->QueryNumRows($query);
        }

        function QueryArray($query) {
          return DB::connect()->QueryArray($query);
        }

        function ResultQueryArray($query) {
          return DB::connect()->ResultQueryArray($query);
        }

        function ResultQueryNumRows($query) {
          return DB::connect()->ResultQueryNumRows($query);
        }





    //название таблицы в базе
    $table="barigo";
    // кол-во пользователей на странице
    $users_on_page="15";
    $sql="select count(id) from `$table`";
    $result = Query($sql);
    // считаем юзеров
    $count=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    // считаем страницы
    $total=ceil($count[0]/$users_on_page);
    // страницы
    if(empty($_GET["p"])){$_GET["p"]="1";}
    $p=$_GET["p"];
    $p=mysql_real_escape_string($p);
    if(!ctype_digit($p) or $p>$total):
        $p="1";
    endif;
    // формируем запрос
    $first=$p*$users_on_page-$users_on_page;
    $zapros=("select * from `$table` WHERE `tovar` LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['nazv'])."%' limit $first, $users_on_page");
    $result = ResultQueryArray($zapros);

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function surnam(){
        var surname = document.getElementById('surname');
        surname.style.border='1px solid #00ff00';
        surname.value='';
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function poisk(){
        var nazv = document.getElementById('nazv');
        nazv.style.border='1px solid #00ff00';
        nazv.value='';
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    .bpdig {
        border: solid 1px #6f4a24 !important;
        background-color: #6e534c !important;
        width: 32px !important;
        height: 14px !important;
        color: #f6d9a6 !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        margin: 2px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    </style>

    <form action="poisk_name.php" method="post">
    Поиск по названию (если хотите определенный товар):
    <input id="nazv" type="text" name="nazv" size="40" value="Сюда вводим слово или полностью название" onClick="poisk()">
    <input type="submit" name="poissk" value="Поиск">
    </form>
    <b>Начинаем с вобора события ... </b>:
      <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" onchange="top.location=this.value">
        <option value="">Выбираем событие</option>
        <option value="?act=all" class="icon-1">Показать всё</option>
        <option value="?act=meloch" class="icon-1">Мелочуха</option>
        <option value="?act=cards" class="icon-2">Карты</option>
        <option value="?act=siyanie" class="icon-3">Сияние удачи</option>
        <option value="?act=zerkal" class="icon-4">Магия зеркал</option>
        <option value="?act=drag" class="icon-5">Драгоценные сундучки</option>
        <option value="?act=torgovoe" class="icon-6">Торговое путешествие</option>
         <option value="?act=meshochki" class="icon-7">Контробандные мешочки</option>

    </select>

    <form action="seach_gold.php" method="post">
    Незнаете на чем заработать ?? Введите вашу скопленную сумму:
    <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" size="1" value="Gold" onClick="surnam()">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Чем БаРыЖитЬ?">
    </form>

    <table border="1">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td align="center"><b>#</b></td>
       <td align="center"><b>Наименование</b></td>
       <td align="center"><b>Куплен за</b></td>
       <td align="center"><b>Продан за</b> </td>
       <td align="center" width="120px"><b>Когда покупать?</b> </td>
        <td align="center" width="500px"><b>Подсчитано на калькуляторе</b></td>
       </tr>
     <?php
     $query = "SELECT id, tovar, kartinka, birjaz, birjas, birjam, aukz, auks, aukm, gosz, goss, gosm, kol, vremya, sobitie, kalkulator FROM `$table` WHERE `tovar` LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['nazv'])."%' limit $first, $users_on_page";
    $result_array = ResultQueryArray($query);
     foreach($result_array as $row)
     { ?>

        <tr>
       <td> <?php print $row['id'] ?></td>
       <td align="center">
       <?php  print $row['tovar'] ?><br />
       <table width="60" height="60" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 2px" background="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/data/artifacts/<?php print $row['kartinka'] ?>" title="<?php  print $row['id'] ?>">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td valign="bottom">
    <?php
    if ($row['kol']>'1') {
    print '<div class="bpdig">'.$row['kol'].'</div>';
    } else {
    print '';
    }
    ?>                                                                                                              </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

       </td>

       <td align="center"><?php print $row['birjaz'] ?> <?php print $row['birjas'] ?> <?php print $row['birjam'] ?></td>
          <td align="center"><?php print $row['aukz'] ?> <?php print $row['auks'] ?> <?php print $row['aukm'] ?></td>
                  <td align="center"><?php print $row['sobitie'] ?></td>


                   <br />
         <td><?php print $row['kalkulator'] ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php  }
    ?>
             </tbody>
       </table>


    <?php
    if($total>1):
        #две назад
        print "<br><div>";
        if(($p-2)>0):
          $ptwoleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?p=".($p-2)."'>".($p-2)."</a>  ";
        else:
          $ptwoleft=null;
        endif;

        #одна назад
        if(($p-1)>0):
          $poneleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?p=".($p-1)."'>".($p-1)."</a>  ";
          $ptemp=($p-1);
        else:
          $poneleft=null;
          $ptemp=null;
        endif;

        #две вперед
        if(($p+2)<=$total):
          $ptworight="  <a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?p=".($p+2)."'>".($p+2)."</a>";
        else:
          $ptworight=null;
        endif;

        #одна вперед
        if(($p+1)<=$total):
          $poneright="  <a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?p=".($p+1)."'>".($p+1)."</a>";
          $ptemp2=($p+1);
        else:
          $poneright=null;
          $ptemp2=null;
        endif;

        # в начало
        if($p!=1 && $ptemp!=1 && $ptemp!=2):
          $prevp="<a href='poisk_name.php' class='first_page_link' title='В начало'><<</a> ";
        else:
          $prevp=null;
        endif;

        #в конец (последняя)
        if($p!=$total && $ptemp2!=($total-1) && $ptemp2!=$total):
          $nextp=" ...  <a href='poisk_name.php?p=".$total."'".$total."' class='first_page_link'>$total</a>";
        else:
          $nextp=null;
        endif;

        print "<br>".$prevp.$ptwoleft.$poneleft.'<span class="num_page_not_link"><b>'.$p.'</b></span>'.$poneright.$ptworight.$nextp;
        print "</div>";
    endif;
    mysql_close();
    ?>

    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так не надо:

```
//название таблицы в базе
    $table="barigo";
    // кол-во пользователей на странице
    $users_on_page="15";
    $sql="select count(id) from `$table`";
    $result = Query($sql);
    // считаем юзеров
    $count=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    // считаем страницы
    $total=ceil($count[0]/$users_on_page);
if(empty($_GET["p"])){$_GET["p"]="1";}
    $p=$_GET["p"];
    $p=mysql_real_escape_string($p);
    if(!ctype_digit($p) or $p>$total):
        $p="1";
    endif;
    // формируем запрос
    $first=$p*$users_on_page-$users_on_page;
    $zapros=("select * from `$table` WHERE `tovar` LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['nazv'])."%' limit $first, $users_on_page");
    $result = ResultQueryArray($zapros);
```

лучше вот так:

```
//название таблицы в базе
    $table="barigo";
    // кол-во пользователей на странице
    $users_on_page="15";
    $sql="select count(id) as mycount from `$table`";
    $result = ResultQueryArray($sql);
    // считаем юзеров
    $count=$result[0]['mycount'];
    // считаем страницы
    $total=ceil($count/$users_on_page);
$p = (empty($_GET['p'])) ? ((intval($_GET['p'])>0) ? intval($_GET['p']) : 1 ) : 1;
if ($p>$total) $p = 1;
        // формируем запрос
        $first=($p-1)*$users_on_page;
        $zapros=("select * from `$table` WHERE (tovar LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['nazv'])."%') limit $first, $users_on_page");
        $result = ResultQueryArray($zapros);
```

А почему не листает... так может у вас столько товаров нет, чтобы их листать

---

**UPD** Как я и говорил, у вас просто нет столько товаров, чтобы их листать

Я поправил вам код и убрал ваши ошибки. Перед тем, как переносить к себе - поправьте ссылки.

```
<?php
        // Параметры подключения к базе данных
        define('DB_SE','server67.0hosting.me');
        define('DB_LO','u8462856_test');
        define('DB_PA','koloiko555');
        define('DB_BA','u8462856_test');


        class DB {
            public static function connect() {
                static $db = null;
                if ($db==null) $db = new DB();
                return $db;
            }
            private $_handle = null;
            private function __construct() {
                $this->_handle = new mysqli(DB_SE, DB_LO, DB_PA, DB_BA);
                if ($this->_handle->connect_error) {
                    die('Connect Error (' . $this->_handle->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->_handle->connect_error);
                }
                $this->_handle->query("SET NAMES utf8");
            }
            public function __destruct() {
              $this->_handle->close();
            }
            public function Test() {
                return $this->_handle;
            }
            public function Query($query) {
                $query = $this->_handle->query($query);
                return $query;
            }
            public function QueryNumRows($query) {
                return (($query===false) ? 0 : mysqli_num_rows($query));
            }
            public function QueryArray($query) {
                if ($query===false) return false;

                unset($arr);
                $i = 0;
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        foreach ($row as $key => $value) $arr[$i][$key] = $value;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $arr = false;
                }
                unset($row);
                return $arr;
            }
            function ResultQueryArray($query) {
                return $this->QueryArray($this->Query($query));
            }
            function ResultQueryNumRows($query) {
                return $this->QueryNumRows($this->Query($query));
            }
        }

        function Query($query) {
          return DB::connect()->Query($query);
        }

        function QueryNumRows($query) {
          return DB::connect()->QueryNumRows($query);
        }

        function QueryArray($query) {
          return DB::connect()->QueryArray($query);
        }

        function ResultQueryArray($query) {
          return DB::connect()->ResultQueryArray($query);
        }

        function ResultQueryNumRows($query) {
          return DB::connect()->ResultQueryNumRows($query);
        }



    //название таблицы в базе
    $table="barigo";
    // кол-во пользователей на странице
    $users_on_page="15";
    $where = "";
    if (!empty($_GET['nazv'])) {
      $_GET['nazv'] = strtoupper(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['nazv'])));
      $where = "WHERE (tovar LIKE '%".$_GET['nazv']."%') ";
    }
    else $_GET['nazv'] = '';


    $sql="select count(id) as mycount from `$table` $where";

    $result = ResultQueryArray($sql);
    // считаем юзеров
    $count=$result[0]['mycount'];
    // считаем страницы
    $total=ceil($count/$users_on_page);

    $p = (!empty($_GET['p'])) ? ((intval($_GET['p'])>0) ? intval($_GET['p']) : 1 ) : 1;
    if ($p>$total) $p = 1;

    // формируем запрос
    $first=($p-1)*$users_on_page;
    $zapros=("select * from `$table` $where limit $first, $users_on_page");
    $result = ResultQueryArray($zapros);

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function surnam(){
        var surname = document.getElementById('surname');
        surname.style.border='1px solid #00ff00';
        surname.value='';
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    .bpdig {
        border: solid 1px #6f4a24 !important;
        background-color: #6e534c !important;
        width: 32px !important;
        height: 14px !important;
        color: #f6d9a6 !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        margin: 2px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    #nazv:focus {
      border: 1px solid #00ff00;
    }
    </style>

    <!--form action="poisk_name.php" method="get"-->
    <form action="" method="get">
    Поиск по названию (если хотите определенный товар):
    <input id="nazv" type="text" name="nazv" size="40" value="<?php echo $_GET['nazv']; ?>" placeholder="Сюда вводим слово или полностью название">
    <input type="submit" name="poissk" value="Поиск">
    <a href="?p=1">Скинуть поиск</a>
    </form>
    <b>Начинаем с вобора события ... </b>:
      <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" onchange="top.location=this.value">
        <option value="">Выбираем событие</option>
        <option value="?act=all" class="icon-1">Показать всё</option>
        <option value="?act=meloch" class="icon-1">Мелочуха</option>
        <option value="?act=cards" class="icon-2">Карты</option>
        <option value="?act=siyanie" class="icon-3">Сияние удачи</option>
        <option value="?act=zerkal" class="icon-4">Магия зеркал</option>
        <option value="?act=drag" class="icon-5">Драгоценные сундучки</option>
        <option value="?act=torgovoe" class="icon-6">Торговое путешествие</option>
         <option value="?act=meshochki" class="icon-7">Контробандные мешочки</option>

    </select>

    <form action="seach_gold.php" method="post">
    Незнаете на чем заработать ?? Введите вашу скопленную сумму:
    <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname" size="1" value="Gold" onClick="surnam()">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Чем БаРыЖитЬ?">
    </form>

    <table border="1">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td align="center"><b>#</b></td>
       <td align="center"><b>Наименование</b></td>
       <td align="center"><b>Куплен за</b></td>
       <td align="center"><b>Продан за</b> </td>
       <td align="center" width="120px"><b>Когда покупать?</b> </td>
        <td align="center" width="500px"><b>Подсчитано на калькуляторе</b></td>
       </tr>
     <?php
     // $query = "SELECT id, tovar, kartinka, birjaz, birjas, birjam, aukz, auks, aukm, gosz, goss, gosm, kol, vremya, sobitie, kalkulator FROM `$table` $where limit $first, $users_on_page";
     // print $query.'<br>';
    // $result_array = ResultQueryArray($query);

    // if ($result_array)
     // foreach($result_array as $row)
     if ($result)
     foreach($result as $row)
     { ?>

        <tr>
       <td> <?php print $row['id'] ?></td>
       <td align="center">
       <?php  print $row['tovar'] ?><br />
       <table width="60" height="60" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 2px" background="http://w2.dwar.ru/images/data/artifacts/<?php print $row['kartinka'] ?>" title="<?php  print $row['id'] ?>">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td valign="bottom">
    <?php
    if ($row['kol']>'1') {
    print '<div class="bpdig">'.$row['kol'].'</div>';
    } else {
    print '';
    }
    ?>                                                                                                              </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

       </td>

       <td align="center"><?php print $row['birjaz'] ?> <?php print $row['birjas'] ?> <?php print $row['birjam'] ?></td>
          <td align="center"><?php print $row['aukz'] ?> <?php print $row['auks'] ?> <?php print $row['aukm'] ?></td>
                  <td align="center"><?php print $row['sobitie'] ?></td>


                   <br />
         <td><?php print $row['kalkulator'] ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php  }
    ?>
             </tbody>
       </table>


    <?php
    if($total>1):
        #две назад
        print "<br><div>";
        if(($p-2)>0):
          //$ptwoleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p-2)."'>".($p-2)."</a>  ";
          $ptwoleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p-2)."'>".($p-2)."</a>  ";
        else:
          $ptwoleft=null;
        endif;

        #одна назад
        if(($p-1)>0):
          //$poneleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p-1)."'>".($p-1)."</a>  ";
          $poneleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p-1)."'>".($p-1)."</a>  ";
          $ptemp=($p-1);
        else:
          $poneleft=null;
          $ptemp=null;
        endif;

        #две вперед
        if(($p+2)<=$total):
          //$ptworight="  <a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p+2)."'>".($p+2)."</a>";
          $ptworight="  <a class='first_page_link' href='?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p+2)."'>".($p+2)."</a>";
        else:
          $ptworight=null;
        endif;

        #одна вперед
        if(($p+1)<=$total):
          //$poneright="  <a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p+1)."'>".($p+1)."</a>";
          $poneright="  <a class='first_page_link' href='?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p+1)."'>".($p+1)."</a>";
          $ptemp2=($p+1);
        else:
          $poneright=null;
          $ptemp2=null;
        endif;

        # в начало
        if($p!=1 && $ptemp!=1 && $ptemp!=2):
          $prevp="<a href='?p=1' class='first_page_link' title='В начало'><<</a> ";
        else:
          $prevp=null;
        endif;

        #в конец (последняя)
        if($p!=$total && $ptemp2!=($total-1) && $ptemp2!=$total):
          //$nextp=" ...  <a href='poisk_name.php?p=".$total."'".$total."' class='first_page_link'>$total</a>";
          $nextp=" ...  <a href='?p=".$total."'".$total."' class='first_page_link'>$total</a>";
        else:
          $nextp=null;
        endif;

        print "<br>".$prevp.$ptwoleft.$poneleft.'<span class="num_page_not_link"><b>'.$p.'</b></span>'.$poneright.$ptworight.$nextp;
        print "</div>";
    endif;
    ?>

    </body></html>
```

Comment: Извините , выходят активные страницы на которые можно листать )

Comment: 1 2 3 ... 5 , а жмешь на вторую страницу и выходит вся таблица с самого начала

Comment: что, даже в моем варианте на второй странице вся страница с самого начала показывается?

Comment: да , я поменял , поменял значение `$users_on_page="15";` на 3 , что б 3 записи выводилось , в поиск воожу маска, выходит первые 3 запроса с маской, жму вторую страницу  , обновляется страница и выводит без поиска всю базу, и при этом даже не листается

Comment: а вы жестокий человек, @Константин =))) вы вероятно теряете из вида то, что при переходе по страницам у вас теряете параметр поиска, который вы первый раз отправили методом $_POST ...

Comment: В вашем случае можно поиск отправлять методом get, а потом его указывать в переходах по страницам... как-то так: 
 $zapros=("select * from `$table` WHERE `tovar` LIKE '%".strtoupper($_GET['nazv'])."%' limit $first, $users_on_page");
    $result = ResultQueryArray($zapros); 

  а в конце 
 
 `if(($p-2)>0):
          $ptwoleft="<a class='first_page_link' href='poisk_name.php?nazv=".$_GET['nazv']."&p=".($p-2)."'>".($p-2)."</a>  ";
        else:
          $ptwoleft=null;
        endif;`

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: не хочет работать

Comment: Я уже намучился с ним )В адресной строке меняется а так листать не хочет (

Comment: Файл целый , с рабочими базами попробуйте пожалуйста поставить у себя и глянуть( просто с ответом на вопрос врятли кто будет уже смотреть его ..

Comment: я так понимаю вы мне не поможете?))

Comment: да я вам написал уже ве, вы просто подставьте и все будет работать

Comment: Да ничего не хочет работать всё подставил

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы не понимаете, что пишите :( даже не пытаетесь

Comment: Обновил ответ. Добавил полный исправленный код файла.

Comment: [Ссылка](http://triass.ru/test/18.php)  Спасибо )) не работает)

Comment: Я целый день сегодня искал примеры , шаблоны , что б все работало и переделать под вывод своей таблицы, ничего путнего у меня не вышло (( то с кодировкой беда , то на аджаксе всё, а я там вообще не могу разобраться((

Comment: Тот пример, что я дал - полностью рабочий, я его запускал у себя и проверял до того, как выложить сюда. Если вернете доступы к базе, то **я запущу и выложу вам видео**. Если у вас что-то не работает в моем скрипте - меняйте хостинг на нормальный.

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, у меня мозг пареный был ) выходила ошибка, не придал значению )) я ж вылаживал данные базы, а кто то удалил эту базу)) всё отлично работает , спасибо вам огромедное